# Calculating hours for a working day spread over 2 separate days - Access SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

For a company I am calculating the worked hours for each employee. The calculation is done by them clocking in- and out.

So it gets inserted in the database as follows:

```
--Record

    Relation: 1101
    Clock Date and time: 2016-09-05 14:00
    Type: Clock IN 
    Worked hours: 0 (always 0 on IN)

--Record

    Relation: 1101
    Clock Date and time: 2016-09-05 16:00
    Type: Clock OUT
    Worked hours: 2 (= clocked out datetime minus clocked in datetime)
```

This always worked untill recently. The company is extended and they now work untill +/- 1 a clock in the night (1:00) while they used to work till max 10 a clock in the evenening (22:00).

In my Access database I am displaying a form that shows total worked hours for a whole day instead of worked hours for each clock in and out. I calculate these hours based on a Min(date) and Max(date) for the specific employee. However, because they sometime now clock OUT in the night, the records get messed up.

For example: Employee A clocks in at 17:00 on 2016-09-05 and works untill 1:00 on 2016-09-06. The MIN gets the 17:00 time but the MAX now also get the 17:00 time (because the MIN/MAX are based on dates and the clocking out is on the Next day..). Because of this the Form is retrieving incorrect values.

Is there an easy way to build something around this?

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT EmpoyeeID
     , EmployeeName
     , EmployeeAge
     , DatePart("yyyy", [ClockDateTime]) AS year
     , DatePart("m", [ClockDateTime]) AS month
     , DatePart("d", [ClockDateTime]) AS day
     , Min(ClockDateTime) AS StartTime
     , Max(ClockDateTime) AS EndTime
     , DateDiff("n", Min([ClockDateTime]), Max([ClockDateTime]))/60 AS TotalWorkedToday
  FROM HourRegistration
 GROUP 
    BY EmpoyeeID
     , EmployeeName
     , EmployeeAge
     , DatePart("yyyy", [ClockDateTime])
     , DatePart("m", [ClockDateTime])
     , DatePart("d", [ClockDateTime]);
```

Comment: quick way around would be: on checkin out if the date has changed then first checkout the previous day like 23:59:59 and checking again 00:00:01 for the new day and then checkout for 1:00:00.

Comment: but in this case you will have to handle multiples checkin per day

Comment: I think you might have to join in to the same table. The first table would have a filter on IN and the second would have a filter on OUT. Then you look for the min OUT date that's greater than the IN date. Just a thought... didn't work out the details, or I would have added a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *correlated subquery* to match up the start and end date/times for each shift. If your [HourRegistration] table contained

```
EmployeeID  ClockDateTime        Type
----------  -------------------  ----
      1101  2016-09-04 09:00:00  IN  
      1101  2016-09-04 17:00:00  OUT 
      1102  2016-09-05 10:00:00  IN  
      1102  2016-09-05 15:00:00  OUT 
      1101  2016-09-05 17:00:00  IN  
      1101  2016-09-06 01:00:00  OUT 
      1101  2016-09-06 18:00:00  IN  
      1101  2016-09-07 01:00:00  OUT
```

then you could create a saved query named [ShiftStartAndEnd] with the code ...

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.EmployeeID, 
    t1.ClockDateTime AS StartDateTime, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(t2.ClockDateTime)
        FROM HourRegistration t2
        WHERE t2.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID
            AND t2.ClockDateTime > t1.ClockDateTime
            AND t2.Type='OUT'
    ) AS EndDateTime
FROM HourRegistration AS t1
WHERE t1.Type='IN';
```

... that returns ...

```
EmployeeID  StartDateTime        EndDateTime        
----------  -------------------  -------------------
      1101  2016-09-04 09:00:00  2016-09-04 17:00:00
      1101  2016-09-05 17:00:00  2016-09-06 01:00:00
      1101  2016-09-06 18:00:00  2016-09-07 01:00:00
      1102  2016-09-05 10:00:00  2016-09-05 15:00:00
```

Then you could use that saved query as the basis for another query that calculates the correct shift length using DateDiff(), similar to what you did before ...

```sql
SELECT
    EmployeeId,
    StartDateTime AS ShiftStart,
    EndDateTime AS ShiftEnd,
    DateDiff("n", StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60 AS ShiftHours
FROM ShiftStartAndEnd
```

... which returns

```
EmployeeId  ShiftStart           ShiftEnd             ShiftHours
----------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------
      1101  2016-09-04 09:00:00  2016-09-04 17:00:00           8
      1101  2016-09-05 17:00:00  2016-09-06 01:00:00           8
      1101  2016-09-06 18:00:00  2016-09-07 01:00:00           7
      1102  2016-09-05 10:00:00  2016-09-05 15:00:00           5
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Was already on to something like this but this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Removing 2 hours from Start time and end time should do the trick.
Replace every `[ClockDateTime]` occurence in your query by `[ClockDateTime] - #1/1/1900 2:0:0#`

Removing 2 hours will set you back to the previous working  situation, as long as the workday stays in the range 3am till 2am next day